# Merge sort - Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to get a merge sort program working, along with a radix sort which is already working, using vectors.

However, the merge sort always gives me the "Vector subscript out of range" error. I know why this error appears, but I can't figure out what change I should make to stop it.

Code:

```
#include "Includes.h"

class Mergesort
{
public:

std::vector<int> mergeSort(std::vector<int> list, int low, int high, int max)
{
    int mid;

    if (low < high) // Does not continue to merge sort when low is less than high.
    { // This will be when the given set is a single number.
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        list = mergeSort(list, low, mid, max); // Split the given set into two halves down the middle.
        list = mergeSort(list, mid + 1, high, max);
        list = merge(list, low, mid, high, max);
    }

    return list;
}

std::vector<int> merge(std::vector<int> list, int low, int mid, int high, int max) // Call requires the bottom, middle and top numbers of the set.
{
    int h, i, j, k;
    std::vector<int> listb(max); // Merged list.
    h = low - 1;
    i = low - 1;
    j = mid;

    while ((h <= mid) && (j <= high))
    {
        if (list[h] <= list[j]) // If the low part of the array is less than the upper middle of the array,
        {
            listb[i] = list[h]; // The next number in the merged array becomes h (initially low part).
            h++; // Increment h to the next part of the array
        }
        else // Otherwise,
        {
            listb[i] = list[j]; // The next number in the merged array becomes j (initially upper middle).
            j++; // Increment j to the next part of the array.
        }
        i++; // Always increment i, the position of the merged array. Starts at the bottom of the array.
    } // End of while loop

    if (h > mid) // If h - the progress from the bottom of the array - is beyond the middle.
    {
        for (k = j; k <= high; k++) // Loop until k is out of the array's range.
        {
            listb[i] = list[k]; // Set the next element in the merged array to the k element in the unmerged.
            i++; // I.e. this starts from the middle, goes to the top of the array copying it into the merged one.
        }
    }
    else // Otherwise, progress has not reached the the j value
    {
        for (k = h; k <= mid; k++) // K will start from h instead
        {
            listb[i] = list[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    // Then,
    for (k = low; k <= high; k++) // Loop through the entire original array, copying the merged array into it.
    {
        list[k] = listb[k];
    }

    return list;
}
};
```

And the main:

```
#include "Mergesort.h"
#include "Radixsort.h"

// Import things we need from the standard library
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

// Define the alias "the_clock" for the clock type we're going to use.
// (You can change this to make the code below use a different clock.)
typedef std::chrono::steady_clock the_clock;

using namespace std;

Mergesort mergeSorter;
Radixsort radixSorter;

void main()
{
int num, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
int inputNumber = 0;

cout << "Please input the size of the list to sort, then press enter:" << endl;
cin >> num;

vector<int> intList(num);

cout << endl << "Please enter a 1 for manual input or 2 for random generation between 0 and 99, then press enter:" << endl;
while (j != 1 && j != 2)
{
    cin >> j;
    if (j != 1 && j != 2)
    {
        cout << "Please enter 1 or 2." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
if (j == 1)
{
    cout << "Now, Please enter the " << num << " numbers, pressing enter between each:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cin >> inputNumber;
        intList[i] = (inputNumber);
    }
}
else if (j == 2)
{
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        inputNumber = rand() % 100;
        intList[i] = (inputNumber);
    }
    cout << "The list generated is: ";
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = intList.begin(); it != intList.end(); it++) // Loops through the list, printing it out.
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

cout << endl << "Now, Please enter a 1 for merge sort or 2 for radix sort, then press enter:" << endl;
while (k != 1 && k != 2)
    {
        cin >> k;
        if (k != 1 && k != 2)
        {
            cout << "Please enter 1 or 2." << endl;
        }
    }

if (k == 1)
{
    intList = mergeSorter.mergeSort(intList, 1, num, num);
    cout << endl << "So, the sorted list using merge sort will be:";
}
else if (k == 2)
{
    intList = radixSorter.radixSort(intList, num);
    cout << endl << "So, the sorted list using radix sort will be:";
}
cout << endl << endl;

for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = intList.begin(); it != intList.end(); it++) // Loops through the list, printing it out.
{
    cout << *it << " ";
}
cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: That out of range exception would be a *dynamic* thing to catch in a debugger.

Comment: Can we see how you call the mergeSort and what arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter max is never used. Normally the right index for mergesort is the ending index (one more than the last index in the vector). In merge(), setting h and i to low-1 will cause the out of range problem, set them both to low, not low -1. Since the merge copies back to list, then mergesort and merge should be void functions using reference for parameters:

```
void mergeSort(std::vector<int> &list, int low, int high)

void merge(std::vector<int> &list, int low, int mid, int high)
```

The main code in mergesort should be:

```
    if ((high-low) > 1)   // nothing to do if 0 or 1 elements
    { // This will be when the given set is a single number.
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, low, mid);
        mergeSort(list, mid, high);
        merge(list, low, mid, high;
```

In merge the early lines should be:

```
    h = low;
    i = low;
    j = mid;

    while ((h < mid) && (j < high))    // change <= to <
```

The other lines using <= should be changed to use <.

The initial call to merge sort should be:

```
    mergeSort(std::vector<int> list, 0, list.size());
```

You may want to use size_t for indices instead of int.

Comment: Cheers, I made your changes. I kept max because I use it to create the list in the merge function which was my initial attempt at stopping crashes.
However it now crashes, with debugging seeming to show it infinitely looping on the return of the mergesort function. Any advice?

Comment: @DuncanBurgess - I forgot to mention, in mergesort() the first if should be if((high - low) > 1) ... . I updated my answer to show this.